# Adding autosuggest feature for airport in flight search form on wordpress plugin

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, plugins

I am working on a wordpress plugin via shortcode method to display a flight search form on a post. Its working fine however I want to add autosuggest feature so whenever a user start typing airport name, it shows them option and user can select. I am aware that airport codes need to be stored somewhere or alternatively I can use publicly available free API to pull airport names/codes when I start typing. Can you please help. Here is my working code which displays the search form alright

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Flight Search Plugin
Description: A plugin to add a flight search form with redirection to iwantthatflight and Kiwi.
Version: 1.9
Author: Your Name
*/

function flight_search_form_shortcode($atts) {
  // Default values for 'from' and 'to' attributes
  $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'from' => 'SYD',
    'to' => 'MEL'
  ), $atts);

  ob_start();
  ?>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #flight-search {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 20px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #flight-search input[type="text"],
    #flight-search input[type="date"],
    #flight-search input[type="number"],
    #flight-search input[type="submit"],
    #flight-search label {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #flight-search input[type="text"],
    #flight-search input[type="date"],
    #flight-search input[type="number"],
    #flight-search input[type="submit"] {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #flight-search input[type="submit"] {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #returnDateField {
      display: block;
    }

    /* Style for radio button container */
    .radio-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    /* Style for radio buttons */
    .radio-container label {
      flex: 1;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  </style>

  <form id="flight-search" action="https://iwantthatflight.com.au" method="get">
    <div class="radio-container">
      <label for="return">
        <input type="radio" id="return" name="flightType" value="return" checked>
        Return
      </label>
      <label for="oneWay">
        <input type="radio" id="oneWay" name="flightType" value="oneWay">
        One Way
      </label>
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="departureAirport" name="oc" placeholder="Departure Airport" value="<?php echo esc_attr($atts['from']); ?>">
    <input type="text" id="returnAirport" name="dc" placeholder="Return Airport" value="<?php echo esc_attr($atts['to']); ?>">
    
    <label for="departureDate">Departure Date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="departureDate" name="dd" placeholder="Departure Date">
    
    <div id="returnDateField">
      <label for="returnDate">Return Date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="returnDate" name="rd" placeholder="Return Date">
    </div>
    
    <input type="number" id="passengers" name="pa" placeholder="Number of Passengers" min="1" max="9" required>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Search Flights">
  </form>

  <script>
    function toggleReturnDateField() {
      const returnDateField = document.getElementById('returnDateField');
      returnDateField.style.display = document.getElementById('return').checked ? 'block' : 'none';
    }

    // Initial toggle
    toggleReturnDateField();

    document.getElementById('flight-search').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      function formatDate(dateString, format) {
        var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };
        return new Date(dateString).toLocaleDateString('en-GB', options).replace(/ /g, format);
      }

      const flightType = document.querySelector('input[name="flightType"]:checked').value;
      const departureDateForIwantThatFlight = formatDate(document.getElementById('departureDate').value, "/");
      let iwantthatflightURL;

      if (flightType === 'return') {
        const returnDateForIwantThatFlight = formatDate(document.getElementById('returnDate').value, "/");
        iwantthatflightURL = `https://iwantthatflight.com.au`;
      } else {
        iwantthatflightURL = `https://iwantthatflight.com.au`;
      }

      window.open(iwantthatflightURL, '_blank');

      // Construct the Kiwi URL with form input values
      const kiwiURL = `https://www.kiwi.com`;

      // Redirect the current window to the Kiwi URL
      window.location.href = kiwiURL;
    });

    // Toggle the visibility of the Return Date field when radio buttons change
    document.getElementById('return').addEventListener('change', toggleReturnDateField);
    document.getElementById('oneWay').addEventListener('change', toggleReturnDateField);
  </script>
  <?php
  return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode('flight_search', 'flight_search_form_shortcode');
?>
```

Comment: The way you do this in WordPress is via an autocomplete widget in jQuery UI. It's too complex for a Stack Overflow answer.